# Wordpress Image Resize fails without Error Message

Tags: uploads, images

I wonder why resizing a jpeg image fails in Wordpress without throwing a PHP Error with memory_limit error or Filesize Error.

The image is 2MB big jpeg with RGB colorspace. Dimensions 4496x4496 (16Megapixel Camera)

A user uploaded it in his profile and since then the user doesn't appear in the Users section anymore. The HTML output just stops at the point the user would come next.

The server runs only with GD and not Imagick.

Server throws a 500 Error Code on upload in Medialibrary, but in the Userprofile the page just goes blank white. Menu still there but Userprofile is unusable.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: you checked logs for error? debug is on? you don't always see an error if one is thrown, can sometimes quietly occur.

Comment: @GhostToast is right. In wp-config.php find the line that says `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change it to true. It's most likely that your server hit its memory limit trying to crunch that file and now you're seeing the repercussions of that issue.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I'll try that and report

Comment: @MikeNGarrett that didn't help as no Error Message appears. Only some Notices and Warnings from the Wordpress core. Funny that Wordpress doesn't recommend some functions since Version 2.0 but still uses them in 3.7.1 :D

Comment: If you're not getting an error that means it's getting what it's expecting while you're still seeing nothing. I would recommend trying to remove that account and image and see if you can't recreate everything at this point.

Comment: memory_limit was the problem. Increased it to 256M and everything works fine. Wonder why no PHP Error was raised by it.